# Reading Data from Excel file which is stored in SharePoint using mule flow

Tags: sharepoint, mule, esb, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to read data from excel (.xlsx) file which is stored in SharePoint. For this I have created a mule flow using HTTP requester for hitting the URL on which the file is present. But in response I am getting encoded data. I tried various transformers to convert the data in readable form but unable to do that.

Below are parts of my **configuration**:

```
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/rest3" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<logger message="Getting Data from sharepoint" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/foldername/filename.xlsx" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"> <http:failure-status-code-validator values="500..599"/> </http:request> 
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/> 
<logger message="Response :-#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

---

**Output** is coming like this:

Þ£={´g?ÊìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£
{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c?rìQŽ=Ê±G9ö(ÇåØ£{”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX
(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,
”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX-ÜÛÂ½-ÜÛÂ½-ÜÛÂ½-ÜÛÂ½-ÜÛBA
ºpo]]¸·…{[hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒ¼Ðà…/4x¡Á
^hðBƒÚ³Ðž…Ê,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX
ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(
ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(
ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(
ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡åX(ÇB9Ê±PŽ…r,”c¡÷¶po÷¶po÷¶po÷¶po

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using byte array to string converter, Please use the data weave transformation like the following so that you will be able to read the the data coming from excel file.

```
<flow name="excel_read_format_dataFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\excel_test"    responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <logger message="Getting Data from sharepoint" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="75a20093-83d4-4612-8d25-5514777ceec2" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\excel.xlsx" mimeType="application/xlsx"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    Person: payload.Sheet1 map
    {
        name:$.First ++ $.Last,
        Age: $.Age
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="Response :-#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal for your valuable response but I am reading file from SharePoint that I have mentioned in the question and when we get the response from SharePont it is in the form of byte-array.